# How to force windows to start centered?

Tags: compiz

How can I force all windows to start centered (excluding dialogs). I can use compiz's Place Windows > Fixed window placement > Fixed placement mode for a specific window (e.g. **class=Gnome-terminal**), but how do i match all windows but dialogs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **Window Management** -> **Place Windows** -> **Placement mode** : `centered` (under the **General** tab)